# Linear-gradient com uma imagem

Tags: javascript, html, css

Queria fazer isto no título da minha box:
[image: ascri]

É um `linear-gradient` com as cores da imagem e no final a imagem.
Tentei os códigos abaixo mas aqui não funcionou. O que está errado?

*script*

```
    <script>
function getAverageRGB(imgEl) {

            var blockSize = 5, // only visit every 5 pixels
                defaultRGB = {r:0,g:0,b:0}, // for non-supporting envs
                canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'),
                data, width, height,
                i = -4,
                length,
                rgb = {r:0,g:0,b:0},
                count = 0;

            if (!context) {
                return defaultRGB;
            }

            height = canvas.height = imgEl.naturalHeight || imgEl.offsetHeight || imgEl.height;
            width = canvas.width = imgEl.naturalWidth || imgEl.offsetWidth || imgEl.width;

            context.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0);

            try {
                data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
            } catch(e) {
                /* security error, img on diff domain */
                return defaultRGB;
            }

            length = data.data.length;

            while ( (i += blockSize * 4) < length ) {
                ++count;
                rgb.r += data.data[i];
                rgb.g += data.data[i+1];
                rgb.b += data.data[i+2];
            }

            // ~~ used to floor values
            rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r/count);
            rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g/count);
            rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b/count);

            return rgb;

        }

        function setTopImage() {
            var rgb = getAverageRGB($("#articleImageSrc").get(0));
            var string = "linear-gradient(to right, rgba(" + rgb.r + "," + rgb.g + "," + rgb.b + ", 1) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), " + $("#articleImageSrc").parent().css("background-image") + " no-repeat center right";


            var luma = 0.2126 * rgb.r + 0.7152 * rgb.g + 0.0722 * rgb.b; // per ITU-R BT.709

            $("#articleImageSrc").parent().css("background", string);

            if (luma < 150)
                $("#articleImageSrc").parent().css("color", "#fff");
        }
    </script>
```

*html*

```
 <div id="articleTopImage" class="card-body" style="background-image: url(https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_FXd9ePuJkQ/WVVqF88kbmI/AAAAAAAA52M/b9aK-jyPb3Umxs1CR7GYp8w8dJ2m7zuCwCKgBGAs/s1600/Furnis%2BArticos.gif);">
                    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_FXd9ePuJkQ/WVVqF88kbmI/AAAAAAAA52M/b9aK-jyPb3Umxs1CR7GYp8w8dJ2m7zuCwCKgBGAs/s1600/Furnis%2BArticos.gif" style="display: none" id="articleImageSrc" crossorigin="" onload="setTopImage()">
                    RE: Aquecimento Caseiro                </div>
```

*css*

```
#articleTopImage {
        width: 100%;
        padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

**Uso bootstrap.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque o valor `70%` do `linear-gradient` por uma função `calc(100% - 170px)`, descontando `170px` da largura da div. Esses `170px` representam a parte da largura da imagem que você deseja visível mais os paddings aplicados na div.

Desta forma, em qualquer largura de tela o resultado é o mesmo:

```js
function getAverageRGB(imgEl) {

            var blockSize = 5, // only visit every 5 pixels
                defaultRGB = {r:0,g:0,b:0}, // for non-supporting envs
                canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'),
                data, width, height,
                i = -4,
                length,
                rgb = {r:0,g:0,b:0},
                count = 0;

            if (!context) {
                return defaultRGB;
            }

            height = canvas.height = imgEl.naturalHeight || imgEl.offsetHeight || imgEl.height;
            width = canvas.width = imgEl.naturalWidth || imgEl.offsetWidth || imgEl.width;

            context.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0);

            try {
                data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
            } catch(e) {
                /* security error, img on diff domain */
                return defaultRGB;
            }

            length = data.data.length;

            while ( (i += blockSize * 4) < length ) {
                ++count;
                rgb.r += data.data[i];
                rgb.g += data.data[i+1];
                rgb.b += data.data[i+2];
            }

            // ~~ used to floor values
            rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r/count);
            rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g/count);
            rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b/count);

            return rgb;

        }

        function setTopImage() {
            var rgb = getAverageRGB($("#articleImageSrc").get(0));
            var string = "linear-gradient(to right, rgba(" + rgb.r + "," + rgb.g + "," + rgb.b + ", 1) calc(100% - 170px), rgba(0,0,0,0)), " + $("#articleImageSrc").parent().css("background-image") + " no-repeat center right";


            var luma = 0.2126 * rgb.r + 0.7152 * rgb.g + 0.0722 * rgb.b; // per ITU-R BT.709

            $("#articleImageSrc").parent().css("background", string);

            if (luma < 150)
                $("#articleImageSrc").parent().css("color", "#fff");
        }
```

```css
#articleTopImage {
        width: 100%;
        padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="articleTopImage" class="card-body" style="background-image: url(https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_FXd9ePuJkQ/WVVqF88kbmI/AAAAAAAA52M/b9aK-jyPb3Umxs1CR7GYp8w8dJ2m7zuCwCKgBGAs/s1600/Furnis%2BArticos.gif);">
                    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_FXd9ePuJkQ/WVVqF88kbmI/AAAAAAAA52M/b9aK-jyPb3Umxs1CR7GYp8w8dJ2m7zuCwCKgBGAs/s1600/Furnis%2BArticos.gif" style="display: none" id="articleImageSrc" crossorigin="" onload="setTopImage()">
                    RE: Aquecimento Caseiro                </div>
```

Comment: Algumas vezes que dou ctrl + f5 no navegador acaba bugando e dando esse erro no console do navegador "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at setTopImage (14:129)
    at HTMLImageElement.onload (14:164)"

Comment: Isso é porque a imagem está sendo carregada antes do jQuery.

Comment: Isto mesmo, valeu <3